Estoy intentando acceder a los Url en mi aplicacion, funcionan bien en Debug, pero en Release no cargan la URL a donde quiero ingresar
En mi funcion para poder acceder a la Url es esta, y al colocar por ejemplo a un texto para acceder, no accede en Release, solo en Debug.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:selectable_navigation_drawer_example/widget/navigation_drawer_widget.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
  try {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
      await launchUrl(uri);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Puedes usar un widget para mostrar el error o simplemente imprimirlo en la consola
    print('Error al lanzar $url: $e');
  }
}

En esta parte tengo mi texto con el icono para acceder al link que quiero, al momento de darle click en el icono, me accede al link en el emulador y en fisico solo si genero el apk en Debug, pero en Release no me marca nada, al instalarlo de manera fisica y tampoco en el emulador:
class AcercadePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Acerca de'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffb9935a),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _launchURL(
                      'https://twitter.com/'), // Asegúrate de reemplazar con el enlace correcto a Twitter
                  child: Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons
                        .twitter, // Usa el ícono de FontAwesome que prefieras
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _launchURL(
                      'https://twitter.com/'), // Asegúrate de reemplazar con el enlace correcto a Twitter
                  child: Text(
                    '@Cuenta',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Probablemente lo que te suceda es que no as agregado en el androidManifest.xml
el permiso para acceder a internet, ya que por defecto viene para debug, pero no para release. Para hacerlo debes ir a

android > app > src > main > androidManifest.xml

y agregar la siguiente linea:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.ejemplo"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- en este nivel debes agregar el permiso de internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application>
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>

de esa forma cuando lo compiles en release vas a poder acceder a internet
